# how is it Regular expression to get 6 lines of substring

Tags: expression

1~6 lines:
/Ab7c142...m1l???t1???ygeeae===13245gea123
/Ab7c142???t1???ygeeae===13245gea123
/Ab7c...m1l???t1???ygeeae===13245gea123
/Ab7c???t1???ygeeae===13245gea123
/???ygeeae===13245gea123
/Ab7c

1./Ab7c142...m1l???t1???ygeeae===13245gea123:

```
/
Ab7c
142
.
..m1l
?
??ygeeae
=
==13245gea123
```

6./Ab7c:

/
Ab7c

Keep array position.

Comment: Could you explain your question a bit more?

Comment: Get the 6-line string, split it into an array, and reserve the array position